# How can I use hook_update_N() to update a FieldConfigStorage?

Tags: 8, entities, updating

This is the code I am attempting to use to update a content type with a new field.  When I run `drush dbup` I get this error.

> PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context in EntityStoageBase.php.

```php
function some_config_update_8101() {
  if (!FieldConfig::load('image_byline')) {
    $config_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'some_config') . '/config/install/field.field.node.main_image.field_image_byline.yml';
    $data = Yaml::parse($config_path);
    \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('field.field.node.main_image.field_image_byline')->setData($data)->save(TRUE);
    $message .= "FieldConfig installed for module some_config.\n";
  }
  else {
    $message .= "It didn't work!\n";
  }

  if (!FieldConfigStorage::load('image_byline')) {
    $config_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'some_config') . '/config/install/field.storage.node.field_image_byline.yml';
    $data = Yaml::parse($config_path);
    \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('field.storage.node.field_image_byline')->setData($data)->save(TRUE);
    $message .= "FieldConfigStorage installed for module some_config.\n";
  }
  else {
    $message .= "That didn't work either!\n";
  }
}
```

How is my code affecting the context of `EntityStorageBase`, if I have not changed code in that file?

Answer (score 1):

[Updating Entities and Fields in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/update-api/updating-entities-and-fields-in-drupal-8), in particular [Updating field storage config items](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/update-api/updating-entities-and-fields-in-drupal-8#s-updating-field-storage-config-items), shows the following example code.

```php
if (!$field_storage_configs = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('field_storage_config')->loadByProperties(array('type' => 'taxonomy_term_reference'))) {
  return;
}

foreach ($field_storage_configs as $field_storage) {
  // Since the usual workflow for field storages do not allow changing the
  // field type, we have to work around it in this case.
  $new_field_storage = $field_storage->toArray();
  $new_field_storage['type'] = 'entity_reference';
  $new_field_storage['module'] = 'core';
  $new_field_storage['settings']['target_type'] = 'taxonomy_term';

  $vocabulary_name = $new_field_storage['settings']['allowed_values'][0]['vocabulary'];
  unset($new_field_storage['settings']['allowed_values']);

  $new_field_storage = FieldStorageConfig::create($new_field_storage);
  $new_field_storage->original = $new_field_storage;
  $new_field_storage->enforceIsNew(FALSE);

  $new_field_storage->save();
}
```

That example code updates an entity field to change its type; it doesn't add an entity field if that doesn't exist. Still, comparing that code with the code you are using, it's clear you are using the wrong class: It's [`FieldStorageConfig`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21src%21Entity%21FieldStorageConfig.php/class/FieldStorageConfig/8.9.x), which is a a configuration entity class, not [`FieldConfigStorage`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21src%21FieldConfigStorage.php/class/FieldConfigStorage/8.9.x), which is a storage handler class.

Being a class that implements an entity, `FieldStorageConfig` has the `create()` static method and the `load()` static method.

The example code is still useful for your case, since it shows how to create a new entity field storage configuration entity. In your case, you will check first the field storage configuration entity doesn't already exist by calling `FieldStorageConfig::load()`.

Answer (score 0):

[FieldConfigStorage::load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityStorageBase.php/function/EntityStorageBase%3A%3Aload/8) isn't static, so you can't use it statically.

Get an instance of `FieldConfigStorage` instead, and use that

```
if ($storage->load('image_byline')) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I have used Node::load()  why is this any different?  dont they both override EntityStorageInterface::load ?

Comment: No, one's for the config (extends `FieldConfigBase`) and the other is for storage (`FieldConfigStorageBase`). Totally different classes, though they complement one another

Comment: The example just uses the wrong class name, should be FieldStorageConfig, wihch is a config entity too. Also, the ID of them is entity_type.bundle.fieldname for the field config, and entity_type.fieldname for the field storage config.